# Working with time units in java

Tags: java, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am building a simple agent base model in Anylogic. What I want to implement is the starvation of the agents. The agent has a `hunger` parameter. I want to set the `hunger` +1 with each hour. I suppose It should be done with the cycle but I have no idea how to start. Can someone help me to build the cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution, however this does not take into account the time to complete the run() method.

```
    public class HourRun implements Runnable {
        private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler 
                                  = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        int period = 1;
        int delay = 0;
        TimeUnit timeUnit = TimeUnit.HOURS;
        ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture;

        public HourRun() {
         scheduledFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this,
                    period, delay, timeUnit);
        }


        @Override
         public void run() {
            // This will be called every hour.
         }
    }
```

If you want it to be one hour between the finish of the run() method, then use use this instead in the constructor.

```
    int initialDelay = 0;
    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this, initialDelay, delay, timeUnit)
```

This will wait 1 hour between all operations, calls, thats being run in your run() method, then call it again.
I am not sure if this is what you wanted.
Maybe this is easier?

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Code here
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

This will run whatever you want in a separate thread that will sleep most of the time. Good luck, I hope I could help you in some way.

Comment: That would be a great solution. However I found out, that anylogic has a scheduler functions where you can just set it up in API:-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the java time api here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Look at java.time.Duration class, it has the functionality that you are looking for. I cannot offer specific help without some code posted.